# Submit a form to a model from my homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, form-for

I have a links model which has all the generic scaffold created for it, however, rather than go to the link#new page, I'd like to submit a form from my homepage that populates a new record.

I only have one text field, but im not sure how to construct the form. I read somewhere you have to specify the controller in the form field but this doesn't appear to be working.

```
<%= form_for(:link, @link) do |f| %>
  <% if @link.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @link.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify anything if you are using default routes.

If the @link is an object that doesn't exist in database, Rails will automatically think this is a form for  `#new`. So the form action will be `/links`, and method is `post`, which is the default resource to `#create`

In your case, you don't need to do anything, just revise the form code to:

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
....
```

Besides, you need to prepare @link object in home controller, something like

@link = Link.new

Comment: Thanks Billy. This works! I'm wondering - does this create an object when the homepage runs? or is it only once I submit the form? I wondering if there is a way to only create the object if the form is submitted... if it isn't doing this already.

Comment: @Adam, this object in #new(or in your HomeController#home) is for your building the form, almost all of its attributes is nil. If you fill the form and submit, the "post" action will send values of what you filled into the receiver, the "create" action. "#create" will get these values from param to build another new object which has no relation with the first one at all. This object is ready to save. The normal process is, if save success, you go back with a success message, if not you go back with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a `url` parameter to the form_for helper

```
<%= form_for :link, url: your_home_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks Thorpe, when you say your home path, are you referring to root, or the path of the link resource? I tried link_path and home_path (i have a controller for home) that didn't appear to call it or is that the page its being called from? Do i need to initiate the mode with link.new as Billy said above?